# how to access or call integrated/attached scanner in my android application?

Tags: android, barcode-scanner

I have IOT Handheld Thermal Android device, which includes scanner and printer integrated in it. I want to use that scanner and printer in my android application, how can i access/call/use that in my application?

your help will be appreciated. thanks

Answer (score 0):

I searched this topic 6 months ago and found something. You can open the Samsung Mobile Print App in your application. I did this.